# Navigate HTML table with input text in every td using arrow key

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, html-table

I have an `HTML table` with input text in every `td`. I'm trying to create a function that will allow arrow keys to navigate my `td's`.

I want to highlight the value of the selected cell when every arrow key is clicked, just like how tab works. Does anyone here have an idea how to achieve this? Thank you.

**Code** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/L7cm8/10/)

Comment: We're expecting you to respect the given guidance you get during asking.

Comment: Add to your css: input:focus { background-color: <your color goes here>; } Looks as though support for this is pretty wide spread. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Comment: @jeff No. I want the text to be highlighted just like when you hit tab.

Comment: Change background-color to color doh.

Comment: please see sample link that I posted. Thanks for the help anyway. What I'm trying to do is when I click arrow key that cell witch compose of input text will automatically select that value, just like the function of the tab key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find input separately, and add a class to **Active** input in `function rePosition()` as,

```
$('#navigate tr td').find('input').removeClass('yourClassforText');
$('#navigate tr td').eq(active).find('input').addClass('yourClassforText');

// to select text inside input
$('#navigate tr td').eq(active).find('input').select();
```

[**old Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7cm8/39/)

### Update

As mentioned another problem by Op, is to remove only selected text.
You need to add a check on a `keydown` event as,

```
var inp = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
if (!(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(inp) || event.keyCode == 96)){
    //if user is entering some text, neglect rePosition & reCalculate events
}
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7cm8/42/)

### Update - 2:

[<kbd>**Demo with thead**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/L7cm8/45/)

Comment: but the text value is not selected/highlighted. I want it to function the way tab key works.

Comment: @x'tian You can achieve that using `select()` in Jquery. answer updated

Comment: Wow. Just what I'm looking for.Thank you! But why it is only allowed with one character only? Every time i try to input a word it keeps on adding just one letter only.

Comment: @x'tian, you have written code on `keydown` event, so its clearing previous value. Need to assign it explicitly. by the way, it could be different Question.. the answer is updated!

Comment: Oh gosh sorry. Another error encountered tried to resolve it before asking to you but didn't know how. Why is that everytime I enter 0(zero) it clears.

Comment: example I entered 1 followed by 0 from then it started to clear.

Comment: `event.keyCode == 96` was needed, check now. It will allow **all numbers and letters**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127602/discussion-between-vikrant-and-xtian).

Comment: I have a question. When I add thead it's now not working.

Comment: If you are getting error on adding `thead`, you can add a separate table which behaves as thead

Comment: I actually already solved the problem. I just add tbody on every call of the table. But it seems not working if I have a two table. It is working on one table only. Please help thank you. :)

Comment: can you post your current code as a new question.. it will help more precisely to understand

Comment: Hi Just posted a new question. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799135/navigate-two-html-table-with-input-text-using-arrow-key

Answer (score 1):

You can get value. Use this code in **re-position** function:

```
alert($('#navigate tr td').eq(active).find('input').val());
```

Comment: But how can I do it without the alert? I mean I just wanted to select/highlight the text so that when I enter new value it will be replaced. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. That is not for one character only. It shows value when re-position function works. That's why, you saw the existing value, not new value. Try more than one on same cell. you will see.

Comment: Oh gosh sorry. Another error encountered tried to resolve it before asking to you but didn't know how. Why is that everytime I enter 0(zero) it clears.