# Navigate Two HTML Table with input text using arrow key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459183/navigate-html-table-with-input-text-in-every-td-using-arrow-key), I asked how to navigate a table cell using an arrow key. And now I'm trying to create another table that will behave the same with the first one.

How to achieve this?

Here is what I have so far:

```js
var active = 0;
//$('#navigate td').each(function(idx){$(this).html(idx);});
rePosition();

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var inp = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if (!(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(inp) || event.keyCode == 96)){
      reCalculate(e);
      rePosition();
      // if key is an arrow key, don't type the user input.
      // if it is any other key (a, b, c, etc)
      // edit the text
      if (e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41) {
        return false;
      }
    }
});

$('td').click(function() {
    active = $(this).closest('table tbody').find('td').index(this);
    rePosition();
});


function reCalculate(e) {
    var rows = $('#navigate tbody tr').length;
    var columns = $('#navigate tbody tr:eq(0) td').length;
    var temp;

    if (e.keyCode == 37) { //move left or wrap
        temp = active;
        while (temp > 0) {
            temp = temp - 1;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // move up
        temp = active;
        while (temp - columns >= 0) {
            temp = temp - columns;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { // move right or wrap
        temp = active;
        while (temp < (columns * rows) - 1) {
            temp = temp + 1;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // move down
        temp = active;
        while (temp + columns <= (rows * columns) - 1) {
            temp = temp + columns;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function rePosition() {
    console.log(active);
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).addClass('active');
    $('#navigate tbody tr td').find('input').removeClass('textClass');
    $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').addClass('textClass');
    $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').select();
    var input = $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').focus();
    scrollInView();
}

function scrollInView() {
    var target = $('#navigate tbody tr td:eq(' + active + ')');
    if (target.length) {
        var top = target.offset().top;

        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: top - 100
        }, 400);
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
td.active{
border:2px solid #2c3e50;
font-weight:bold;
background-color:#ddd;
}

.textClass{ 
    font-weight:bold; 
}

input:focus {
    outline: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="navigate">
    <thead>
            <th> CELL 1</th>
            <th> CELL 2</th>
            <th> CELL 3</th>
            <th> CELL 4</th>
            <th> CELL 5</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<br><br>

<table border="1" id="table2">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please refer to this link for the sample demo.

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/nbadnkb8/)

Comment: You want to continue navigation in the second table when you reach end of the first table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit sweating research, it gets to the proper solution. As we can't click inside the TDs of any other tables: we need to change the way of finding the index of `td`.

Currently it's as:

```
$(this).closest('table tbody').find('td').index(this);
```

This always returns the first table `td` indexes.

Below code helps finding exact index of TD where current focus is:

```
$('table td').index(this);
```

Though it looks a simple line.. little huge Research made it that small...

[**Working DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nbadnkb8/6/)

Comment: @x'tian, was difficult & time consuming.. so posting as a new answer ✍(◔◡◔) ... let me know if its *kills* out the issue..

Comment: such an genius trick! Thank you buddy. Sorry for the late reply. Lost my connection for two days.

Comment: Hi buddy I have encountered another proble, I tried to disabled some of my textbox. Then every time I remove the selected cell then try to edit it its bouncing to the edited textbox.

Comment: I actually posted new question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903118/navigate-table-cell-using-arrow-key-and-ignore-disabled-cell.

Comment: Also I tried to do this if ($("#input1").prop("disabled", true)) { $(this).focus();}

Comment: let's continue this on your New Question

Answer (score 1):

**Send Table** `id` **in** `$('td').click`

```
$('td').click(function() {
    active = $(this).closest('table tbody').find('td').index(this);
    var tableid=$(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    console.log(tableid);
    rePosition(tableid);
});
```

**And Change Function** `rePosition()`

```
function rePosition(tableid) {
    console.log(active);
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#'+tableid+' tbody tr td').eq(active).addClass('active');
    $('#'+tableid+' tbody tr td').find('input').removeClass('textClass');
    $('#'+tableid+' tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').addClass('textClass');
    $('#'+tableid+' tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').select();
    var input = $('#'+tableid+' tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').focus();
    scrollInView(tableid);
}
```

**Live Demo** **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/df6ufxou/1/)**

**Snippet Example**

```js
var active = 0;
//$('#navigate td').each(function(idx){$(this).html(idx);});
rePosition();

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var inp = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if (!(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(inp) || event.keyCode == 96)){
      reCalculate(e);
      rePosition();
      // if key is an arrow key, don't type the user input.
      // if it is any other key (a, b, c, etc)
      // edit the text
      if (e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41) {
        return false;
      }
    }
});

$('td').click(function() {
    active = $(this).closest('table tbody').find('td').index(this);
    var tableid=$(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    console.log(tableid);
    rePosition(tableid);
});


function reCalculate(e) {
    var rows = $('#navigate tbody tr').length;
    var columns = $('#navigate tbody tr:eq(0) td').length;
    var temp;

    if (e.keyCode == 37) { //move left or wrap
        temp = active;
        while (temp > 0) {
            temp = temp - 1;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // move up
        temp = active;
        while (temp - columns >= 0) {
            temp = temp - columns;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { // move right or wrap
        temp = active;
        while (temp < (columns * rows) - 1) {
            temp = temp + 1;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // move down
        temp = active;
        while (temp + columns <= (rows * columns) - 1) {
            temp = temp + columns;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function rePosition(tableid) {
    console.log(active);
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#'+tableid+' tbody tr td').eq(active).addClass('active');
    $('#'+tableid+' tbody tr td').find('input').removeClass('textClass');
    $('#'+tableid+' tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').addClass('textClass');
    $('#'+tableid+' tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').select();
    var input = $('#'+tableid+' tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').focus();
    scrollInView(tableid);
}

function scrollInView(tableid) {
    var target = $('#'+tableid+' tbody tr td:eq(' + active + ')');
    if (target.length) {
        var top = target.offset().top;

        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: top - 100
        }, 400);
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
td.active{
    border:2px solid #2c3e50;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#ddd;
}


.textClass{ 
 font-weight:bold; 
}

input:focus {
 outline: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="navigate">
 <thead>
   <th> CELL 1</th>
   <th> CELL 2</th>
   <th> CELL 3</th>
   <th> CELL 4</th>
   <th> CELL 5</th>
 </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<br><br>

<table border="1" id="table2">
   <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="CELL 5" /></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [**THIS DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nbadnkb8/4/)

If two tables or more than that... use `Class` to identify all of them

I have written `class="tblnavigate"` to call in table cells in Javascript.

So, reposition function looks like:

```
function rePosition() {
    console.log(active);
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.tblnavigate tbody tr td').eq(active).addClass('active');
    $('.tblnavigate tbody tr td').find('input').removeClass('textClass');
    $('.tblnavigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').addClass('textClass');
    $('.tblnavigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').select();
    var input = $('.tblnavigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').focus();
    scrollInView();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The backspace must behave as it's functionality so, exclude it in `keydown` function as,

```
if ((!(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(inp) || e.keyCode == 96)) && e.keyCode != 8){ ... }
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nbadnkb8/5/)

Comment: Ops. Another question why is that when I type to the selected cell and try to backspace it remove everything I type?

Comment: @x'tian, thinking of answering your other pending questions (>‿◠)✌

Comment: I actually encountered another problem. Hehehe. Try to click the second table using mouse click. It loses its focus and can't navigate. Is it possible that when I click the cell using my mouse it will focus and allow the arrow key function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129006/discussion-between-vikrant-and-xtian).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function with below code and check:

```
function reCalculate(e) {
    var rows = $('#navigate tbody tr').length;
    var columns = $('#navigate tbody tr:eq(0) td').length;
    var temp;

    if (e.keyCode == 37) { //move left or wrap
        temp = active;
        while (temp > 0) {
            temp = temp - 1;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // move up
        temp = active;
        while (temp - columns >= 0) {
            temp = temp - columns;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { // move right or wrap
        temp = active;
        while (temp < (columns * rows) - 1) {
            temp = temp + 1;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // move down
        temp = active;
        while (temp + columns <= (rows * columns) - 1) {
            temp = temp + columns;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function rePosition() {
    console.log(active);
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).addClass('active');
    $('#navigate tbody tr td').find('input').removeClass('textClass');
    $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').addClass('textClass');
    $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').select();
    var input = $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').focus();
    scrollInView();
}

function scrollInView() {
    var target = $('#navigate tbody tr td:eq(' + active + ')');
    if (target.length) {
        var top = target.offset().top;

        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: top - 100
        }, 400);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Check Updated Demo: [Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nbadnkb8/3/)**

Comment: not able to click on second table.. are you sure, answer is working..?

Answer (score 0):

I used this on a recent project and it worked perfectly: https://gist.github.com/krcourville/7309218