# Navigate table cell using arrow key and ignore disabled cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that act like an excel. User are allowed to navigate entire table using arrow keys. But when I tried to disable some of its textboxs it is still capturing the disabled cell and when I tried to enter a text the value is adding on the editable cell. How can I able to resolve this? Thank you.

Here is what I have so far.

```js
var active = 0;
//$('#navigate td').each(function(idx){$(this).html(idx);});
rePosition();

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var inp = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  if (!(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(inp) || event.keyCode == 96)) {
    reCalculate(e);
    rePosition();
    // if key is an arrow key, don't type the user input.
    // if it is any other key (a, b, c, etc)
    // edit the text
    if (e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41) {
      return false;
    }
  }
});

$('td').click(function() {
  active = $(this).closest('table tbody').find('td').index(this);
  rePosition();
});


function reCalculate(e) {
  var rows = $('#navigate tbody tr').length;
  var columns = $('#navigate tbody tr:eq(0) td').length;
  var temp;

  if (e.keyCode == 37) { //move left or wrap
    temp = active;
    while (temp > 0) {
      temp = temp - 1;
      // only advance if there is an input field in the td
      if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
        active = temp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) { // move up
    temp = active;
    while (temp - columns >= 0) {
      temp = temp - columns;
      // only advance if there is an input field in the td
      if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
        active = temp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 39) { // move right or wrap
    temp = active;
    while (temp < (columns * rows) - 1) {
      temp = temp + 1;
      // only advance if there is an input field in the td
      if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
        active = temp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) { // move down
    temp = active;
    while (temp + columns <= (rows * columns) - 1) {
      temp = temp + columns;
      // only advance if there is an input field in the td
      if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input').length != 0) {
        active = temp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function rePosition() {
  $("#input1, #input3").prop("disabled", true);

  console.log(active);
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).addClass('active');
  $('#navigate tbody tr td').find('input').removeClass('textClass');
  $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').addClass('textClass');
  $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').select();
  var input = $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').focus();
  scrollInView();
}

function scrollInView() {
  var target = $('#navigate tbody tr td:eq(' + active + ')');
  if (target.length) {
    var top = target.offset().top;

    $('html,body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: top - 100
    }, 400);
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
td.active {
  border: 2px solid #2c3e50;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.textClass {
  font-weight: bold;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="navigate">
  <thead>
    <th>CELL 1</th>
    <th>CELL 2</th>
    <th>CELL 3</th>
    <th>CELL 4</th>
    <th>CELL 5</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="input1" type="text" value="CELL 1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input2" type="text" value="CELL 2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input3" type="text" value="CELL 3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input4" type="text" value="CELL 4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input5" type="text" value="CELL 5" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="input1" type="text" value="CELL 1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input2" type="text" value="CELL 2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input3" type="text" value="CELL 3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input4" type="text" value="CELL 4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input5" type="text" value="CELL 5" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="input1" type="text" value="CELL 1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input2" type="text" value="CELL 2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input3" type="text" value="CELL 3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input4" type="text" value="CELL 4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input5" type="text" value="CELL 5" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="input1" type="text" value="CELL 1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input2" type="text" value="CELL 2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input3" type="text" value="CELL 3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input4" type="text" value="CELL 4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input5" type="text" value="CELL 5" />
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>



  <table border="1" id="table2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="inputb1" value="CELL 1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="inputb2" value="CELL 2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="inputb3" value="CELL 3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="inputb4" value="CELL 4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="inputb5" value="CELL 5" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb1" value="CELL 1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb2" value="CELL 2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb3" value="CELL 3" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb4" value="CELL 4" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb5" value="CELL 5" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb1" value="CELL 1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb2" value="CELL 2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb3" value="CELL 3" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb4" value="CELL 4" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb5" value="CELL 5" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb1" value="CELL 1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb2" value="CELL 2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb3" value="CELL 3" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb4" value="CELL 4" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb5" value="CELL 5" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb1" value="CELL 1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb2" value="CELL 2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb3" value="CELL 3" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb4" value="CELL 4" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb5" value="CELL 5" />
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: are there any *Disabled* cells in your HTML. I can't see any!

Comment: I placed the disable property using javascript as I bind my textbox backend.

Comment: $("#input1, #input3").prop("disabled", true); I put it on reposition function. I think I placed it wrong :(

Comment: `reposition` is getting called on `td` click... If you are sure which `TD` to disable.. you should make it on `document.ready()` event

Comment: I tried to do it but still the problem is when I enter a text the value is adding on a editable cell.

Comment: The disabling part is working but when I tried to enter a text on the disabled cell the value is entering on the enabled cell.

Comment: thats bcuz Focus remains on Enabled cell

Comment: but when i tried to put the focus on disabled cell the enabled cell also turning into disabled. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129495/discussion-between-vikrant-and-xtian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per requirement, You can use

```
find('input:not(:disabled)')
```

With this, you can skip **disabled** cell and focus on next Enabled cell directly.
Example:

```
if (e.keyCode == 37) { //move left or wrap
        temp = active;
        while (temp > 0) {
            temp = temp - 1;
            // only advance if there is an input field in the td
            if ($('.tblnavigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input:not(:disabled)').length != 0) {
                active = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

[**Complete Solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/nbadnkb8/10/)

And, if you want to explicitly focus on Disabled Cell, you can use Mouse Click for it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to modify the find selector in the recalculate method. Updated the snippet. 
Instead of `find('input')` use `find('input:not(:disabled)')`

Hope this helps.

```js
var active = 0;
//$('#navigate td').each(function(idx){$(this).html(idx);});
rePosition();

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var inp = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  if (!(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(inp) || event.keyCode == 96)) {
    reCalculate(e);
    rePosition();
    // if key is an arrow key, don't type the user input.
    // if it is any other key (a, b, c, etc)
    // edit the text
    if (e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41) {
      return false;
    }
  }
});

$('td').click(function() {
  active = $(this).closest('table tbody').find('td').index(this);
  rePosition();
});


function reCalculate(e) {
  var rows = $('#navigate tbody tr').length;
  var columns = $('#navigate tbody tr:eq(0) td').length;
  var temp;

  if (e.keyCode == 37) { //move left or wrap
    temp = active;
    while (temp > 0) {
      temp = temp - 1;
      // only advance if there is an input field in the td
      if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input:not(:disabled)').length != 0) {
        active = temp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) { // move up
    temp = active;
    while (temp - columns >= 0) {
      temp = temp - columns;
      // only advance if there is an input field in the td
      if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input:not(:disabled)').length != 0) {
        active = temp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 39) { // move right or wrap
    temp = active;
    while (temp < (columns * rows) - 1) {
      temp = temp + 1;

      // only advance if there is an input field in the td
      if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input:not(:disabled)').length != 0) {
        active = temp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) { // move down
    temp = active;
    while (temp + columns <= (rows * columns) - 1) {
      temp = temp + columns;
      // only advance if there is an input field in the td
      if ($('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(temp).find('input:not(:disabled)').length != 0) {
        active = temp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function rePosition() {
  $("#input1, #input3").prop("disabled", true);

  console.log(active);
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).addClass('active');
  $('#navigate tbody tr td').find('input').removeClass('textClass');
  $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').addClass('textClass');
  $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').select();
  var input = $('#navigate tbody tr td').eq(active).find('input').focus();
  scrollInView();
}

function scrollInView() {
  var target = $('#navigate tbody tr td:eq(' + active + ')');
  if (target.length) {
    var top = target.offset().top;

    $('html,body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: top - 100
    }, 400);
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
td.active {
  border: 2px solid #2c3e50;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.textClass {
  font-weight: bold;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="navigate">
  <thead>
    <th>CELL 1</th>
    <th>CELL 2</th>
    <th>CELL 3</th>
    <th>CELL 4</th>
    <th>CELL 5</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="input1" type="text" value="CELL 1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input2" type="text" value="CELL 2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input3" type="text" value="CELL 3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input4" type="text" value="CELL 4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input5" type="text" value="CELL 5" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="input1" type="text" value="CELL 1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input2" type="text" value="CELL 2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input3" type="text" value="CELL 3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input4" type="text" value="CELL 4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input5" type="text" value="CELL 5" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="input1" type="text" value="CELL 1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input2" type="text" value="CELL 2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input3" type="text" value="CELL 3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input4" type="text" value="CELL 4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input5" type="text" value="CELL 5" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="input1" type="text" value="CELL 1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input2" type="text" value="CELL 2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input3" type="text" value="CELL 3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input4" type="text" value="CELL 4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="input5" type="text" value="CELL 5" />
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>



  <table border="1" id="table2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="inputb1" value="CELL 1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="inputb2" value="CELL 2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="inputb3" value="CELL 3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="inputb4" value="CELL 4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="inputb5" value="CELL 5" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb1" value="CELL 1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb2" value="CELL 2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb3" value="CELL 3" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb4" value="CELL 4" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb5" value="CELL 5" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb1" value="CELL 1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb2" value="CELL 2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb3" value="CELL 3" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb4" value="CELL 4" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb5" value="CELL 5" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb1" value="CELL 1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb2" value="CELL 2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb3" value="CELL 3" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb4" value="CELL 4" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb5" value="CELL 5" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb1" value="CELL 1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb2" value="CELL 2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb3" value="CELL 3" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb4" value="CELL 4" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="inputb5" value="CELL 5" />
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```